# Open Source Particle Tracing Software

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, electrons, resource-recommendations, software

I am fairly new to this forum. I am designing an ionospheric plasma testing environment in a thermal vacuum chamber and to do so I require some form of multi-physics package for simulations .. such as CST Particle Studio or COMSOL Particle Tracing. However, I do not have access to such software. Can anyone recommend any open source alternatives please?

Answer (score 1):

Trackpy is a Python package for particle tracking in 2D, 3D, and higher dimensions.

http://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/stable/
https://github.com/soft-matter/trackpy

The Matlab Particle Tracking Code Repository
Daniel Blair and Eric Dufresne

http://site.physics.georgetown.edu/matlab/

Particle tracking using IDL
John C. Crocker and Eric R. Weeks

http://www.physics.emory.edu/faculty/weeks/idl/

Comment: IDL is closed source, though the code linked may be freely available.

Comment: There is an open source version of IDL called GDL (http://gnudatalanguage.sourceforge.net/) which is unfortunately no longer supported.  But it does work for IDL 7.1 and below, and supports some functionality from IDL 8 as they describe.  Its possible that it would work :/

Comment: As @tmwilson26 says, GDL does exist, but from complaints easily found online & personal experience, it is hardly a satisfactory replacement (i.e., it is missing many functions found in IDL).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is too late to help you but it may help others. Have a look at our open source gui based tracking software.

https://github.com/MikeSmithLabTeam/particletracker

There are a series of video tutorials to help you get started:

https://particle-tracker.readthedocs.io/en/master/rstfiles/tutorials.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/378141)